# Python Won't Update a Variable Outside of My For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm following another tutorial on CodeSignal, and this time it wants me to figure out what the missing numbers are in a sequence from smallest to largest in a list. I figured out how to sort the list, but the program is not working as expected.

Here's the code that I have right now:

```
def solution(Statuses):
    Statuses.sort()
    firstNum = 0
    print(Statuses)
    for i in range(len(Statuses) - 1):
        if Statuses[(firstNum + 1)] - firstNum == 1:
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("no")
        print(firstNum)
        firstNum += 1
solution([6, 2, 3, 8])
```

Here's the output that I get with the code above:

```
[2, 3, 6, 8]
no
0
no
1
no
2
```

Here's the expected output:

```
[2, 3, 6, 8]
yes
0
no
1
no
2
```

The reason that the first yes/no... *thing* should say "yes" is because the 2 and 3 that you can see in the list's difference is 1, while the others are not.

What's the issue?

Comment: `Statuses[(firstNum + 1)]` why `+ 1`? you never check `Statuses[0]` and `Statuses[1]`.

Comment: You aren't comparing two elements from the list, you are comparing an element with  an index - which are completely unrelated.  And note that `firstNum` is pointless, your `for` loop is generating the indexes you need in the `I` variable.

Comment: @jasonharper what information is stored in the variable in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is check if the difference between two successive numbers in a list is 1. This is not what you are doing here :

```
if Statuses[(firstNum + 1)] - firstNum == 1:
```

the correct code is

```
if Statuses[firstNum + 1] - Statuses[firstNum] == 1:
```